# Swapping between multiple images using images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So i need to create a program that can change between multiple images when clicking multiple buttons. Imaging having an initial image with 4 different buttons, and each of the buttons have another image allocated. So the program would be able to switch from the initial image to image 4 and then to image 2 and so on. The code I have so far is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Changing the Image</h1>
    <img src="image1.png" id="imagenpordefecto" width="300" height="300">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage1()" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage2()" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage3()" value="Button 3" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage4()" value="Button 4" />
    <script>
        function changeImage1() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
            if (image.src.match("image1.png")) {
                image.src = "image2.png";
            }
            else {
                image.src = "image1.png.png";
            }
        }
    function changeImage2() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
            if (image.src.match("image1.png")) {
                image.src = "image2.png";
            }
            else {
                image.src = "image1.png";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically i know how to do it with 2 images, but not with multiple, this is because with the code I have, I would need to know which image is currently displaying in order to change it, using the "match" function. Any help is very much appreciated it.

Comment: You just need one function for all the buttons: when the button is clicked, you swap the image source with `image<number>.png`, where `<number>` can be provided as an argument. Not sure why you need to perform the regex matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it by passing in the image name to the function, this avoids repeating code and making a function for every image.

I've used images from https://pixabay.com/ but you could of course use relative paths to your own images `onclick="changeImage('image1.png')"`.

```js
var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');

function changeImage(uri) {
  image.src = uri;
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<h1>Changing the Image</h1>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/22/02/37/background-3249063_960_720.png" id="imagenpordefecto" width="300" height="300">

<input type="button" onclick="changeImage('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/27/18/54/technology-1283624_960_720.jpg')" value="Button 1" />
<input type="button" onclick="changeImage('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/node-js-736399_960_720.png')" value="Button 2" />
<input type="button" onclick="changeImage('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/08/04/12/programmer-1653351_960_720.png')" value="Button 3" />
```

If you want to use a list/array and cycle though them try something like:

```js
var images = [
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/22/02/37/background-3249063_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/27/18/54/technology-1283624_960_720.jpg',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/node-js-736399_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/08/04/12/programmer-1653351_960_720.png'
];

var current = 0;

var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
image.src = images[current];
buttonState();

function backImage() {
  current = current === 0 ? current : current - 1;
  image.src = images[current];
  buttonState();
}

function nextImage() {
  current = current === images.length - 1 ? current : current + 1;
  image.src = images[current];
  buttonState();
}

function buttonState() {
  document.querySelector('[value="Back"]').disabled = current === 0;
  document.querySelector('[value="Next"]').disabled = current === images.length - 1;
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<h1>Changing the Image</h1>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/22/02/37/background-3249063_960_720.png" id="imagenpordefecto" width="300" height="300">

<input type="button" onclick="backImage()" value="Back" />
<input type="button" onclick="nextImage()" value="Next" />
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?
I simply removed the match thing, if you noticed.

```
<script>
        function changeImage1() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
            image.src = "pic1.png";
        }
        function changeImage2() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
            image.src = "pic2.png";
        }
        function changeImage3() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
            image.src = "pic3.png";
        }
        function changeImage4() {
            var image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto');
                image.src = "pic4.png";
        }
    </script>
```

You could also refactor to retrieve *imagenpordefecto* only once and save in a variable *image* that can then be reused. I believe I read somewhere that "retrieving"(probably not the correct term) takes time and resources, so better save in a variable if reused. Though, there are caveats with that as well.

```
  <script>
        let image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto'); // <------<<<<
        function changeImage1() {
            image.src = "pic1.png";
        }
        function changeImage2() {
            image.src = "pic2.png";
        }
        function changeImage3() {
            image.src = "pic3.png";
        }
        function changeImage4() {
                image.src = "pic4.png";
        }
    </script>
```

And as per **Terry's** comment, one could make it even simpler by providing one function "to rule em all" and just provide it with an argument:

```
   <img src="pic1.png" id="imagenpordefecto" width="300" height="300">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(1)" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(2)" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(3)" value="Button 3" />
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage(4)" value="Button 4" />


    <script>
        let image = document.getElementById('imagenpordefecto'); // <------<<<<
        function changeImage(number) {
            image.src = "pic" + number + ".png";
        }
    </script>
```